# Check an ajax response is json or else using prototype js

Tags: ajax, prototype-js

It is a simple question to all of our dear magento developer.

***How can*** i check ***ajax response type is json or else*** using ***prototype js***  whenever ***request header*** is not defined as [application/json](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Response/prototype/responseJSON/)

> requestHeaders: {Accept: 'application/json'}

**My prototype ajax request is:**

```
new Ajax.Request(url,{
    method:'POST',
   parameters:params,
    onSuccess:function(transport){

    }.bind(this)
    });
```

Now  i am trying  to ***send different type of  header response basic on  my logic.***

**Condition:** 
if condition  is match with rule  then ***send json response***  using below code:

> ```
>   public function testAction() {
>       if(ConditionMATCh) {
>                       $data = array('user_id' => 1, 'name'=> 'Amit' );
>               $result=Mage::helper('marketplace/assignfollowup')->addonFollowerList($data);
>               return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
>           }
> ```

***Else   render a layout  below code:***

> ```
>  public function testAction() {
>       if(ConditionMATCh) {
>                       $data = array('user_id' => 1, 'name'=> 'Amit' );
>               $result=Mage::helper('marketplace/assignfollowup')->addonFollowerList($data);
>               return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
>           } else {
>                                 $this->loadLayout();
>                                 $this->renderLayout();
>                                 return;
>       }
>   }
> ```

**My JavaScript ajax request cod is below**

> ```
> new Ajax.Request(url,{
>     method:'POST',
>     parameters:params,
>     onSuccess:function(transport){
>           if(responseISJson){
>
>       // do someting
>   }else{
>       // do other
>   }
>
>     }.bind(this)
>     });
> ```

Now try to do some ***logic basic of response type(Json/other)*** on above ***prototye ajax request  example***.

### Question: How can i track that response  Json or else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a function which is  fulfill my requirement.

**Function name:**  `isJSON()`.

***just add below two line code  and  get result***

> ```
>      var response = transport.responseText;
>             if (response.isJSON()) {...
> ```

**code is :**

> ```
>    new Ajax.Request(url,{
>     method:'POST',
>     parameters:params,
>     onSuccess:function(transport){
>     var response = transport.responseText;
>     if (response.isJSON()) {
>       //It is json reponse
>       // do someting
>   }else{
>       // do other
>   }
>
>     }.bind(this)
>     });
> ```